# How do I add a leader between the ToC chapter number and title with tocloft?

Tags: tocloft

The title of my question says it all. Is it possible to add a leader between the number and title of a chapter in the ToC with `tocloft`? I tried doing this: `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Normally, leaders are inserted -- it at all -- between the sectioning header and the associated page number. How wide is the gap, in your document's ToC, between the chapter number and title? Incidentally, did you try `\ldots` instead of `\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}`?

Comment: Yeah I tried using `\ldots`, but it didn't give me the desired effect. I'm actually using `\renewcommand{\cftdot}{---}` with `\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0}` to make an unbroken straight line instead of dots. As of right now, the `\cftchapnumwidth` is `1.7cm`, but I don't mind adjusting it. I just want space between the chapter number and chapter title, and add this line separator between the two. The problem with using a fixed character or set of characters is that there's chapters 1-30 lined up on one page. Some chapter numbers are two-digits so the distance between the number and title is off

Answer (score 1):

I didn't troubleshoot thoroughly enough. Using `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` actually works, but you need to increase `\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{4cm}`.